# TradingView - When I go Long, I want my Stop Loss at Previous Bar's Low

Tags: pine-script

I have a Strategy in TradingView that goes long based on certain conditions. Working wonderful if I use integers or percentages for StopLoss and TakeProfit.

However, I really want to set the StopLoss at the previous bars low.

I can't seem to save a variable at the time of the execution of the Long.

Below doesn't work because low[1] is updated on every candle:

```
inpTakeProfit   = input(2.0, title='Take Profit %', type=float)/100
takeProfitValue = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + inpTakeProfit)
inpStopLoss     = low[1]
stopLossValue = inpStopLoss
entry = strategy.position_avg_price
useTakeProfit   = inpTakeProfit  > 0 ?  takeProfitValue : na
useStopLoss     = inpStopLoss    > 0 ?  stopLossValue   : na
```

How do you save a variable and have it remain static?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Stop as last bars low and profit as percentage
entry = strategy.position_avg_price
inpTakeProfit   = input(2.0, title='Take Profit %', type=float)/100
takeProfitValue = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + inpTakeProfit)
useTakeProfit   = inpTakeProfit  > 0 ?  takeProfitValue : na
**inpStopLoss     = valuewhen(allConditions, low, 0)**
stopLossValue = inpStopLoss
useStopLoss     = inpStopLoss    > 0 ?  stopLossValue   : na
```